# Bold and Italic layer labels with Python in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, labeling

I'm trying to apply some labeling properties to a layer using Python. Everything went fine, except the way I tried to apply the Bold and Italic settings. Here is a part of the code:

```
  layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fieldName", field.name())
  layer.setCustomProperty("labeling", "pal")
  layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/enabled", "True")
  layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontFamily", "Arial Narrow")

  if self.dlg.pt6.isChecked():
    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontSize", "6")
  if self.dlg.pt8.isChecked():
    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontSize", "8")
  if self.dlg.pt10.isChecked():
    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontSize", "10")

  if self.dlg.chkbold.isChecked():
    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/weight", "Bold")
    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontWeight", "75")
    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/Weight", "Bold")

  if self.dlg.chkitalic.isChecked():
    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontItalic", "True")
```

Comment: Have you tried using `75` instead of `"75"` and `True` instead of `"True"`? Also, I believe `"labeling/weight"` isn't supported (only `"labeling/fontWeight"`).

Comment: Thanks. I think removing the quotes is a good idea. Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Great! This works.

Comment: Just posted my comment as an answer. Great that you've solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it depends on the font you're using. Try alternating among the following options:

**Bold**:

```
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/namedStyle", "Bold")
```

*Italic*:

```
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/namedStyle", "Italic")
```

**Bold** and *Italic*:

```
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/namedStyle", "Bold Italic")
```

If neither Bold or Italic are selected in your plugin, you could use:

```
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/namedStyle", "Regular")
```

These options correspond to styles in the QGIS GUI:

[image]

This should do the trick!